# Printing the first Ascii char in an interrupt based printf

Tags: assembly

I am learning assembler for PDP-11, and as part of my assignment I had to write a `printf` that will use interrupts. r0 points to the current char and the string is 0 terminated.

The printf:

```
printSend: cmpb     #0, (r0) 
           beq  printfEnd
           mov  #100,   @#tps 
           wait
           br   printfSend
```

The interrupt:

```
printfOut:  movb (r0)+,     @#tpb
            rti
```

After some testing it became clear that I need to deal with the first char differently. Because if the printer is ready when I start waiting then I will wait forever. So I added the following code to the beginning of the printf:

```
        cmpb    #0,     (r0)
        beq     printfEnd
        tstb    @#tps
        bpl     printfSend
        movb (r0)+,     @#tpb
```

which worked fine, however, it does not feel right. I imagine branching will take some time, in which the printer might be ready, and it feels like too much code.

I wish there was a way to un-ready the printer. Is this possible? Or, is there a standard way of doing it?

Comment: To "un-ready" the printer, you usually press a button on the printer itself. Not something you do from the computer end.

Comment: For some reason we call the consul printer, it felt wrong at first but i got used to it. So you say I shuled just deal with some extra code? (notice I now use capital letters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, never use general purpose registers to pass the information between a non-`ISR` and `ISR` contexts (here I assume the hardware interrupt handling routines), it is a bad practice. Use memory for that instead.  If you need to use a register inside `ISR` then save its value on the stack and then restore before you return from the interrupt.

Now, to your question. From my memories, the `IRQ` logic in PDPs is edge-triggered, so I believe you just miss the opportunity to get an interrupt as you already 'spent' the possibility. Try to disable `IE` bit on `LPT` status register inside the `ISR` after you just wrote the current byte to the data register when the next byte to send is `NUL`, i.e.:

```
printfOut:  movb (r0)+,     @#tpb
        tstb (r0)
        bne done
        clr @#tps
done:   rti
```